# deauthorize from google plus api

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

how to deauthorize app from google plus:

```
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

          onResult(Status status) {
            // mGoogleApiClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
            // Trigger app logic to comply with the developer policies
          }

        });
```

giving error : The method setResultCallback(ResultCallback) in the type PendingResult is not applicable for the arguments (new ResultCallback(){})
the code is from "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in" in section "revoking access tokens and deauthorize app"

Answer (score 1):

```
onResult(Status status)
```

Must be :

```
public void onResult(Status status)
```

That was as simple as that for me ! That is quite bothersome that google's example code is not usable as it is...
Also please check that you have imported these :

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

check, that you import the proper `ResultCallback`.

the ResultCallback interface has the following signature of `onResult`:

```
public abstract void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result arg0);
```